# "На всякую несносность он отвечал ударом шпаги"?

Tags: выбор-слов, точное-словоупотребление

Синонимы не помогают. Какое слово (одно) задумано?

> Используя свои ресурсы и связи, раздавая высшим чинам свои поместья,
>   он умудрялся раз за разом уходить от наказания за свои преступления.
>   **На всякую несносность он отвечал ударом шпаги.** Влиятельные его враги пусть не боялись прямого укола в сердце, однако опасались его
>   интриг и тайной мести.

По смыслу-то - да, чего персонаж не мог снести = несносность.

Comment: Намеки,  нападки,  дерзость, смысл ведь "на все,  что ему не нравилось", так?

Comment: Да. Я выбрала "дерзость". Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На мой взгляд, слово употреблено *неудачно*: **несносность** обозначает *постоянное* качество, единичным проявлением которого (на что возможно отреагировать чем-то вроде удара шпагой) может быть **дерзость**.

Comment: Дерзость - ТО слово, спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

В общем-то такое слово есть в словарях, вот у Ефремовой: https://classes.ru/all-russian/russian-dictionary-Efremova-term-55436.htm

Это существительное по прилагательному несносный - то, что трудно снести (вынести). Всё нормально, не нужно его менять.

Comment: А народ нас поймёт?

Comment: Я думаю, если человек задумается над словом - он  вдумчивый, образованный, начитанный , значит поймёт, а если не очень и способен переработать только лёгкое чтиво - просто не заметит этого слова.

Answer (score 1):

*Люди **задевали** здесь воображение Леонардо да Винчи только **своею несносностью** и, отрешенные от неба в своей душевной жизни, не могли внести в его творчество никаких новых для него элементов* (И. Свеченовская).

*Тредиаковский специально подчеркивает в этой связи, что Суффен — поэт, **известный** своим тщеславием, бездарностью и **несносностью**, явно намекая на то, что все эти качества в равной мере характеризуют и Сумарокова* (Б. Успенский).

*О **несносности** Евгения Моргунова ходили легенды, а многие именитые режиссеры и вовсе отказывались с ним работать* (Тайны кино).

"А народ нас поймёт?" Думаю, что поймёт.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы заменил "несносность" на "неучтивость". Или на "проявление неучтивости":

На всякое проявление неучтивости он отвечал ударом шпаги.

Comment: Но ведь неучтивость на много градусов ниже несносимости=несносности. Так мы факт исказим - ради красного словца.

Comment: Да, Вы правы.

Добавлю только, что неучтивость понятие относительно объективное (в рамках устоявшегося общества или сословия). Тогда как несносность более субъективна и может зависеть от раздражительности индивидуума.

Но я согласен с тем, что "дерзость" будет ближе по смыслу -- если только автор подразумевает дерзость подлинную, а не имеет в виду повышенную вспыльчивость и обидчивость своего героя.

Comment: Речь о Франческо Ченчи (и это не лечится): https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%87%D0%B8,_%D0%91%D0%B5%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5

Comment: Если речь идёт о паталогической личности, то здесь надо переспросить автора, каким именно смыслом он желает неделить это предложение. Может быть, в этом конкретном случае "неучтивость" действительно уместней, чем "дерзость".

Comment: То есть как спичка от косого взгляда, да?

Comment: да, я так это понимаю